# Css for internet explorer

Tags: css

can anybody help me here. I don't know much about css hacks but I am trying to add a margin to my element for only internet explorer. The element is showing correctly in all the browsers except ie. I am using elementor plugin. I tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    div.elementor-heading-title{
        margin-top: 100px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: which version of ie? as that works for me in ie11: https://jsfiddle.net/ua0gbzby/

Comment: I will work only 10+  version of ie

Comment: Please add the IE version to the ticket.

Comment: It's version 11. Can I also maybe show the url of my site because the other browsers are showing correctly even edge

Comment: You need to create a [MCVE] demonstrating your problem.  Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  My guess though is that you probably have a more specific style overriding your margin or you have included the above in the wrong place if the above is not working